# Titanium webviews - remove the native iPhone scroll-limit dropshadow

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, webview, titanium, dropshadow

When scrolling a webview in Titanium for iPhone, some ugly dropshadows appear to define the limits of the content.  These are the native shadows you also get when scrolling to the ends of a page in mobile safari.

See: http://bit.ly/dh11Gx

Would anyone know of a simple way to remove these from within Titanium, or possibly directly within the html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to actually fix this by placing the webview within another element - tableview or view, and giving the webview a fixed height that was equal or less than that of the enclosing element.

eg. 
webview = 200px high

tableviewrow = 200px high

tableviewrow.add(webview);

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on what you're trying to accomplish within your layout.  Does it have to be a webView?  If not, you can set a scrollView to not have the bounce when scrolling nor the scrollbar.

Maybe try the property disableBounce = false; for the webView and see if that works?